# Cross Correlation of Signals of Different Lengths

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft, cross-correlation

I am trying to calculate the cross correlation between two signals of different lengths in Java, using the Cross Correlation Theorem:

```
corr(lag) = ifft(fft(a) * cconj(fft(b)))
```

I have tried zero padding my data sets to make them of equal length, but it results in very small correlation coefficients. How can I measure the cross correlation without severely impacting results?

Comment: Some actual code might help addressing your problem. Include tests with desired and actual results. You may like to use the normalized cross-correlation so that entries in the correlation array will be scaled between 0 (no correlation) to 1 (identical)